# In a bitcoin multi-sig wallet, can i determine which of the m of n keys were used to send bitcoin?

Tags: multi-signature

I'm particularly interested in this for large n multi-sig wallets. For example, if m-of-n is 4-of-6, and 6 different people (e.g. 6 non-profit co-directors) hold each of the n keys. If one day all of the wallet is emptied just using 4 (m) keys, will the 2 (n-m) people be able to determine which were the 4 keys and thereby the 4 co-directors that emptied the wallet?

Answer (score 2):

The signatures and public keys have to be supplied to spend the coins so yes you can tell by looking at the spending transaction on the blockchain.

Comment: So then I would need to know which individuals hold which public keys from the beginning, when the wallet is created?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: This mechanism is also only generally available to the participants in the multisig construction, if the common advice of no key reuse is followed.